# Dumb TV or Monitor with speakers

Tags: usb, monitors, hdmi, television

I'm looking for a Dumb TV or basically a flat panel monitor with built in speakers. Would want it to be somewhere between 15" to 20". Just want something that I can use in my workshop shop or tote around the yard when I'm working or hanging outside. We cut the cord with our Cable Provider about a year back so I if it has or doesn't have a TV tuner doesn't matter. I'd be using this with a Chromecast so it needs to have HDMI input and a powered USB port would be ideal. Anyone have any recommendations on something like this?